# passing Kotlin Tuple to a Java function

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Kotlin function which returns a map like `Map<String, Pair<String, String>>`. I need to pass it to a java function and java does not seem to have a Pair data structure. What would be the best way to pass such a structure to the Java function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use Pair (`import kotlin.Pair;`)
, since that is compiled to a JVM class, this isn't any different from using any other kotlin class in java.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Comment: Oh, I had no idea. Sorry very new to this and did not know one could do this intraop!